# Delete folders that don't have a character in their name

Tags: command-line, server, delete

I have a list of folders that all have a year in parentheses, except for a few:

```
./Folder 1 (2001)
./Folder 2 (2008)
./Folder 3
./Folder 4 (1994)
./Folder 5 (2005)
./Folder 6
```

I would like to delete the folders (and contents therein) that **don't have a parentheses** in their name via the command line. In the above example, `Folder 3` and `Folder 6`.

I know that if I wanted to delete all the folders **that do have a parentheses** in their title I could do:

```
rm -rf *(*
```

But I don't know how to do it the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

With bash's extended globbing (which should be enabled by default, in Ubuntu)

```
$ shopt extglob 
extglob         on
```

it should be possible to use the glob pattern `!(*\(*\)*)`

e.g. given

```
$ tree
.
├── Folder 1 (2001)
├── Folder 2 (2008)
├── Folder 3
├── Folder 4 (1994)
├── Folder 5 (2005)
└── Folder 6

6 directories, 0 files
```

then

```
$ rm -ri !(*\(*\)*)
rm: remove directory 'Folder 3'? y
rm: remove directory 'Folder 6'? y
```

leaving

```
$ tree
.
├── Folder 1 (2001)
├── Folder 2 (2008)
├── Folder 4 (1994)
└── Folder 5 (2005)

4 directories, 0 files
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash, use `GLOBIGNORE`:

```
$ echo *
Folder  1 (2001) Folder  2 (2008) Folder  3 Folder  4 (1994) Folder  5 (2005) Folder  6
$ GLOBIGNORE='*\(*'
$ echo *
Folder  3 Folder  6
```